# ApiHash ****** isn't registered when i send message to telegram in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, telegram

I am developing an website using MVC .I have to send some notification to telegram using my website .so i add this nuget :

```
PM> Install-Package Notificatio.TelegramClient
```

It installed an i use this code to send my message :

```
var api = NotificatioApi.Initialize("your_api_hash");           
api.SendMessage("phone_number", "Your message")
```

I get an api_hash from the telegram website but after running i get this error :

```
ApiHash ******* isn't registered
```

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add Api-hash from site owner, not telegram site.